# Empty item as HTML <option> for abp-select

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, abp, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In Razor pages, you can specify an empty first item for a `select` by doing something similar to this:

```html
<select asp-for="SelectedTags" asp-items="Model.TagOptions">
    <option value="">Choose a tag</option>
</select>
```

Is there an option for the `abp-select` Tag Helper such as:

```html
<abp-select asp-for="Mentor.RegionId" asp-items="Model.Regions">
    <option value="">Choose a region</option>
</abp-select>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-select-tag-helper

Comment: depends which ui components you're using...abp is just the framework you can use a variety of ui components with eg Telerik, Blazorise

Comment: I opened a PR in ABP: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/8781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible as of ABP 4.3.0, because `AbpSelectTagHelperService` modifies `output.Content` without calling and using the result of `output.GetChildContentAsync`.

```cs
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var innerHtml = await GetFormInputGroupAsHtmlAsync(context, output);

    ...

    if (suppress)
    {
        output.SuppressOutput();
    }
    else
    {
        output.TagName = "div";
        ...
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(innerHtml);
    }
}

protected virtual async Task<string> GetFormInputGroupAsHtmlAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var selectTag = await GetSelectTagAsync(context, output);
    ...
}
```

```cs
protected virtual async Task<TagHelperOutput> GetSelectTagAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    ...

    var selectTagHelperOutput = await selectTagHelper.ProcessAndGetOutputAsync(GetInputAttributes(context, output), context, "select", TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag);

    // selectTagHelperOutput.Content.SetHtmlContent(childContent); // Missing
    ...
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/8781
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-5.0#inspect-and-retrieve-child-content